# Spring Boot app calling another Spring Boot app over HTTPS and getting SSL certificate verification error: "signature check failed"

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat, https

I have two Spring Boot applications each running in their own docker container.

One is REST Client and the other is REST API.

When the client calls the API ( i.e. `GET https://localhost:8443/api/someResource` ), I get the following error:

**Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed**

Each spring boot app has its own keystore and self-signed certificate stored in 
*src/main/resources/keystore.p12*

... here's what I have in the application.yml files:
following properties:

```
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: somethingsecure
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias: client or server (depending which .yml file your looking at)
```

I tested this outside of Docker and everything worked fine! I simply exported the API certificate out of the keystore.p12 file and imported it into my JRA cacerts file.

You can see from my REST Client Dockerfile, I do the same thing there:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
EXPOSE 8443
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY client.jar client.jar
COPY server.crt server.crt
RUN keytool -v -import -noprompt -alias server -file server.crt -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "client.jar"]
```

I've turned SSL debugging on and can see the following:

```
trustStore is: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore

...

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=localhost, OU=Development, O=Microgen, L=Fleet, ST=Hampshire, C=UK
  Issuer:  CN=localhost, OU=Development, O=Microgen, L=Fleet, ST=Hampshire, C=UK
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4c1fbbc3
  Valid from Mon Apr 16 09:49:33 GMT 2018 until Tue Apr 16 09:49:33 GMT 2019
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Matches the used host name the name in certificate?

Comment: Yes, the CN is localhost in the certificate and the REST Client calls https://localhost:8443/api/blahblahblah

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert but when exporting the certificate and importing I wonder if in your new location the certificate chain is the same as the location you took it from.

Here is a link that might provide some insight, under the Cause section

https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/connecting-to-ssl-services-802171215.html

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to figure this out this morning. The server certificate was simply corrupt and since regenerating, this worked.